# how to get userdetails post successful login for hawtio on wildfly so that data can be shown as per user

Tags: wildfly, rbac, hawtio

I have enabled hawtio security on wildfly by adding the following in standalone.xml:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="hawtio.authenticationEnabled" value="true" />
    <property name="hawtio.realm" value="jboss-web-policy" />
    <property name="hawtio.role" value="admin,viewer" />
</system-properties>
```

and then created an application user using add-user.sh and i am able to successfully login using the credentials i added for that user.

Now, I want that only data specific to that user should be visible on my plug ins and for that i need user details of the current authenticated user, but i am not able to find any suitable example implementing this.
What should be the best approach to go ahead with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to get the login user from your Hawtio plugin.

1. Inject `userDetails` into the AngularJS controller for your plugin. `userDetails.username` will return the name of the login user. See this example:
   https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/hawtio-1.5.10/hawtio-web/src/main/webapp/app/activemq/js/preferences.ts#L7
2. Access the servlet endpoint http://localhost:8080/hawtio/user, which returns the name of the login user as string.

Either way is ok but the option 1 would be the first choice. The option 2 can be used when it is required out of the normal AngularJS app lifecycle such as being across page reload.

Comment: One more query, is it possible to get user role from this userDetails? If yes, then how? @Tadayoshi Sato

Comment: There is no easy way to get the roles of a user on Hawtio at this moment.